# Trigger a table by entering the value of another table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to trigger the calculation of a table by entering the value of another table. there are two table, first one has input tab called profit_rate and the other one supposed to do a calculation as cost * currency_rate * profit_rate(in the other table), however, it doesn't work when I entering profit_rate.

JavaScript

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {

            $(".update_row_data").change(function() {
                var auto_array = {};
                action = $(this).closest('tr').data('action');
                form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input, select');
                var profitRate = Number($("#profit_rate").val());
                var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {
                        auto_array[element.name] = element.value, profitRate;
                });

    console.log(myArray);
    var pprice = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pprice');

    pprice_val = Math.round(auto_array['cost'] * profitRate * auto_array['currency_rate'];
    
    if(!isNaN(pprice_val) && pprice_val != 'Infinity') {
        pprice.val(pprice_val);
    }
    form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        action: action,
                        form_data: form_data,
                    },
                    url: 'update.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == 1){
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
        };

        </script>
```

html code

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<input name="profit_rate" size="3" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data     profit_rate" id="profit_rate" value="<?php echo $res['profit_rate'];?>">
</td></tr></table>

<table>
<tr data-action="update_price" data-row-id="<?php echo $res['id'];?>">
<td><input name="cost" type="text" class="update_row_data cost" id="cost" value="<?php echo $res["cost"];?>"></td>
<td><input name="currency_rate" type="text" class="update_row_data currency_rate" id="currency_rate" value="<?php echo $res["cost"];?>"></td>
<td><input name="pprice" size="5" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="update_row_data pprice" value="<?php echo $res["pprice"] ;?>"></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Please provide [mre], with sample data, and you have syntax error missing    ), should resolve that first by yourself before positing.

Comment: where is `.pprice` in above code ?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have added pprice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `next` table to get all `inputs` inside tr .In below code i have use `each` loop to iterate over `trs` then get required input value and calcuate them and add them to `json-array`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var auto_array;
$(".profit_rate").change(function() {
  var myArray = []
  //find closest table->next table
  var elem = $(this).closest('table').next('table');
  var action = elem.find('tr').data('action');
  console.log(action)

  var profitRate = Number($("#profit_rate").val());
  //looping 
  elem.find('tr').each(function() {
    //get cost
    var cost = $(this).find('input[name=cost]').val();
    //get curency rate
    var currecy_rate = $(this).find('input[name=currency_rate]').val();
    //calculate profit
    var profit_total = Math.round(cost * profitRate * currecy_rate)
    $(this).find('input[name=pprice]').val(profit_total)
    //add to json object
    auto_array = {};
    auto_array["cost"] = cost;
    auto_array["currecy_rate"] = currecy_rate;
    auto_array["pprice"] = profit_total;
    myArray.push(auto_array) //push to array
  });
  console.log(myArray)
  //your ajax call 

});
//on change of cost
$(".cost").change(function() {
  var cost = $(this).val();// that value
  var currecy_rate = $(this).closest('tr').find(".currency_rate").val();
  var profitRate = Number($("#profit_rate").val());
  var profit_total = Math.round(cost * currecy_rate * profitRate); $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=pprice]').val(profit_total)
});
//onchange of currecncy value
$(".currency_rate").change(function() {
  var currency_rate = $(this).val();
  var cost = $(this).closest('tr').find(".cost").val();
  var profitRate = Number($("#profit_rate").val());
  var profit_total = Math.round(cost * currency_rate * profitRate); $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=pprice]').val(profit_total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="profit_rate" size="3" style="" type="text" class="update_row_data     profit_rate" id="profit_rate" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr data-action="update_price" data-row-id="<?php echo $res['id'];?>">
    <td><input name="cost" type="text" class="update_row_data cost" id="cost" value="25"></td>
    <td><input name="currency_rate" type="text" class="update_row_data currency_rate" id="currency_rate" value="25"></td>
    <td><input name="pprice" size="5" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="update_row_data pprice" value="12"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-action="update_price" data-row-id="<?php echo $res['id'];?>">
    <td><input name="cost" type="text" class="update_row_data cost" id="cost" value="20"></td>
    <td><input name="currency_rate" type="text" class="update_row_data currency_rate" id="currency_rate" value="20"></td>
    <td><input name="pprice" size="5" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="update_row_data pprice" value="12"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. how about if I also want make change of the pprice by changing value of cost and currency_rate?

Comment: so you need to mutliply both value of change of `cost` or `currecncy_rate` ?

Comment: yes, actually I need pprice to change when I change profit_rate or cost or currency_rate

Comment: i have updated my code check if that works for you .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the code works fine. Because I am not good at js, I spent a day to complete my code to save to the database, but can not save, if you can also help for this base on the code I provided, I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you asked another question for this ? will try to help you there.

Comment: Hi, here is the link for the other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846536/how-to-save-to-database-by-using-ajax